# Question on the center of universal enveloping algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a unitary group $U(n)$ and $G’$ is a subgroup $U(m)$. (i.e. $m\le n$)

Let $\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}'$ be the complexified Lie algebra of $G,G’$ and $\mathfrak{z},\mathfrak{z}’$ be the center their universal enveloping algebra.

Let $\mathfrak{t}’$ and $\mathfrak{t}$ be their maximal toral subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}'$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $\mathfrak{t}’ \subset \mathfrak{t}$.

Since $\mathfrak{t}’ \subset \mathfrak{t}$, I guess that there is a natural canonical surjection $\mathfrak{z}, \to \mathfrak{z},’$ which is compatible with domain restriction morphism $C^{\infty}((U(n)) \to C^{\infty}(U(m))$.(Here, we regards elements of $\mathfrak{z}$ and $\mathfrak{z}'$ as differential operators.)

More precisely, I am asking the exitence of canonical surjection $p:\mathfrak{z}, \to \mathfrak{z}’,$ such that for $\phi \in C^{\infty}((U(n))$ and $X \in \mathfrak{z}’$,  $X \cdot (\phi|_{U(m)})=(Y \cdot \phi)|_{U(m)}$ where $Y$ is an arbitrary element in $p^{-1}(X)$.

Such $p$ does exists? If so how can we construct it? Some expert has alluded to me to use Harish-Chandra isomorphism. But I have no idea how to use it in this situation.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For a particular case ZUgl(n) to ZUgl(N). Take a look at section 10. "Coherence property of quantum immanants and shifted Schur polynomials" , of the https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9605042 there is kind of "averaging" map discussed there .

Comment: I assume $\mathfrak{t}, \mathfrak{t}'$ are the relevant maximal tori, which implies that you are choosing tori. Does this mean that your "canonical" surjection is allowed to depend on the choice of maximal tori?

Comment: @Alexander, Thank you! It seems to holds for unitary groups. Do you think that it does hold for other classical groups also?

Comment: @user44191, Yes! I mean canonical map as the natural map once we fix relevant maximal tori.

Comment: Does https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107389/about-the-map-s-mathfrakg-g-rightarrow-s-mathfrakh-h-for-h answer your question ?

Comment: @Alexander, Thank you very much! Though it is the dual version of what I am seeking for, it is similar. I am finding some sufficient condition such map be surjective! In the meanwhile, may I ask you some stupid question? I am wondering whether Lie algebra of complex Lie group equal to complexification of a Lie algebra.

For example, let $G=GL_N(\mathbb{R})$ and $G_{\mathbb{C}}= GL_N(\mathbb{C})$ and $g_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $g_{\mathbb{C}}$ be their corresponding real and complex Lie algebra.

Then $g_{\mathbb{C}}= g_{\mathbb{R}} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$?

Thank you very much always!

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, g_C = g_R \times C

Comment: @Alexander, Hello! Do you think that such coherence property also holds for reductive groups not only for classical groups? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391427/the-coherence-property-of-center-of-universal-enveloping-algebra-for-reductive-l